# Why svg fill color behave strange in chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

UPDATE:

Turns out this is [a bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=754612) and it was fixed in Chrome Canary.
You can test it by installing Chrome Canary or just wait until Chrome update.

OLD QUESTION:

Here's a simple SVG path filled with a color using CSS:

```css
svg {
    fill: rgb(122, 102, 50);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 600" class="card-cover" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 100 300 C 400 300 350 200 500 200 L 500 200 C 650 200 600 300 850 300 Z" />
</svg>
```

What I'm expecting is – the color is `rgb(122, 102, 50)`. However, here's the result:

[image: screenshot1]

As you can see there's 2 regions with different colors, each slightly different from what I was expecting:

[image: screenshot2]

[image: screenshot3]

Why does this happen and can I fix this?

Comment: Presumably a bug, report it to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I have edited your question so that it is simpler to understand and answer. Please avoid code/screenshot only questions in the future. When seeking for debugging help, please provide all the necessary stuff to make it reproducible (looks like you did) and describe the expected and the actual behaviour. Also, please take a https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read the "asking" section of https://stackoverflow.com/help . Best regards

Comment: This effect appears on my machine only at certain scale, I agree with @Robert Longson, please, report it as a bug.